Fourier Transform of a moderate decreasing function is of compact support, show that it satisfies the Lipschitz Condition
Suppose $f$ is of moderate decrease $\left(|f(x)|\leq\frac{A}{1+x^2}\right)$
and that its Fourier Transform $\hat{f}$ is supported in $I=\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$.
I proved that $\hat{f}$ is also of moderate decrease and its also continuous. I would like to know if it is possible to show, that $\hat{f}$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition, or is differentiable in $I$.
\begin{align*}
 \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{|\hat{f}(\xi+h)-\hat{f}(\xi)|}{h}
    &\leq \lim_{h\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|f(x)\right|\left|e^{-2\pi i x\xi }\right|\frac{\left|e^{-2\pi ixh}-1\right|}{h}dx\\\\
    &\leq\lim_{h\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|f(x)\right|\frac{\left|e^{-2\pi ixh}-1\right|}{h}dx.
\end{align*}
I know I would need a dominating function, so I could use the DCT. But I cant come up with one. (Alternatively, I tried to proof the Lipschitz condition, but also there, I cant get to a proper conclusion).
Does anyone could give me a hint, how to proceed at this point?

What does moderate decrease mean ? But anyway, compact support on the Fourier transform implies analytic ... but it can still grow at infinity.

I added it. its like a weaker version of rapid decrease. Does the function f itself is not necessary differentiable. Is the fourier transform still analytic?

Oh, I thought you were asking if $f$ was Lipschitz, not if it was the case for its Fourier transform. The Fourier transform is not analytic ...
